# LSTM Grid Search

Tags: keras, neural-network, lstm, grid-search, hyperparameters

I have a code below which implements an architecture (in grid search), to yield appropriate parameters for input, nodes, epochs, batch size and differenced time series input.

The challenge I have is to convert the neural network from just having one LSTM hidden layer, to multiple LSTM hidden layers.

At the moment, I could only run the code with Dense-type hidden layers, without having any errors thrown, otherwise I get dimension errors, tuple errors and so on.

The problem is only persistent in the neural network architecture section.

**Original code that works:**

```
def model_fit(train, config):
    # unpack config
    n_input, n_nodes, n_epochs, n_batch, n_diff = config

    # Data
    if n_diff > 0:
        train = difference(train, n_diff)

    # Time series to supervised format
    data = series_to_supervised(train, n_in=n_input)

    train_x, train_y = data[:, :-1], data[:, -1]

    # Reshaping input data into [samples, timesteps, features]
    n_features = 1
    train_x = train_x.reshape((train_x.shape[0], train_x.shape[1], n_features))

    # Define model for (Grid search architecture)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(n_nodes, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
    model.add(Dense(n_nodes, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(n_nodes, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(n_nodes, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    # Compile model (Grid search architecture)
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

    # fit model
    model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=n_epochs, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=0)
    return model
```

**Modified LSTM-hidden layer code, that fails to run:**

```
# Define model for (Grid search architecture)
model = Sequential() 
model.add(LSTM(n_nodes, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input, n_features), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(n_nodes, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(n_nodes, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(n_nodes, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1)))
```

**Another variant that also threw an error - ValueError: Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_4 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (34844, 1)**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_nodes, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input, n_features), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(n_nodes, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_input))
model.add(LSTM(n_nodes, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(n_nodes, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(n_features)))
```

Could anyone with any suggestion please help me ?

Comment: You may not want `return_sequences=True` before connecting to `Dense()`.

Comment: @KidaeKim Thank you, it indeed solved my issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the future, consider using automated *hyperparameter tuning packages* such as Talos (https://github.com/autonomio/talos).

Answer (score 0):

Try to set return_sequences=False at the last layer.

Comment: This is more like a comment